# Menu bar in Nautilus, Ubuntu Software Center and Terminal, not global menu bar

Tags: 15.10

I'm not sure how this happened but firstly, the Ubuntu Unity Plugin was disabled in Unity for no reason. I then installed Gnome flashback via the text-only session. After I got the Unity plugin fixed the Unity desktop returned to normal, but for some strange reason only nautilus and other related programs have this issue(Menu bar not in the title bar). But programs like Google Chrome, Spotify and system settings are normal. Is there a solution to this?
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit too late but if other user encountered this issue like me, jut issue the command

`sudo killall lightdm`

Try to login and it will fix the problem. Another is uninstalling compiz config settings manager.